# Memory build up when using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

```
class DataItemCache {
    private CompletableFuture future;

    public DataItemCache() {
        future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

    public void saveItemAsync(Object dataItem) {
        future = future.thenRunAsync(() -> {
            saveItemSync(dataItem); // Saves the item to Elastic Search
        });
    }

    public void waitForWriteComplete() {
        future.get();
    }
```

This class is being used as follows:

```
class DataProcessorIntegrationTest {
    @Inject private DataItemCache dataItemCache;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Setup Guice for injection
    }

    @Test
    public void testWorkflow() {
        int numItems = 1000;
        for (int index = 0; index < numItems; index++) {
            DataItem obj = ... // build data item
            dataItemCache.saveItemAsync(obj);
        }

        // I have code to periodically dump the heap during this wait

        dataItemCache.waitForWriteComplete();

        // assert that Elastic Search has 1000 items
    }
}
```

Number of DataItems allocated just before waitForWriteComplete() returns is 1000, and immediately afterwards is 0. I expect that the number of DataItems will be less than 1000, since *some* of them have finished writing to Elastic Search (I know that from the console logs).

When I run this code is production, I get OOM. Inspecting the heap at the time of OOM shows millions of DataItem and CompletableFuture objects. Obviously, many of them must have completed writing and returned from the saveItem method. Why are such DataItem and CompletableFuture objects not getting released?

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not with that amount of information. How would you solve a problem of "I put a lot of things into memory and I run out of memory, I have some theories but you probably shouldn't trust them". The pseudocode (right? that's not your real code, is it?) doesn't show anything useful, except that you apparently know how to call some methods.

Comment: Clearly whatever you're doing wrong is in code you haven't provided.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How about showing your real code, but only the relevant parts. If you claim that `dataItem` and `CompletableFutures` aren't being freed, then show the parts of the code where you'd expect them to become eligible for GC.

Comment: I have added more detail to the question. Does it make it clearer now?

Comment: The `future` that you have in `DataItemCache` is useless, you don't need it to run async code, and your `waitForWriteComplete()` will not wait for anything since `future` is already completed from the start. `get()` does not wait for dependent tasks. In fact, I don't even think that `thenRunAsync()` keeps track of any dependent stages after the future on which it is called has been completed (that could be the source of memory leaks). Anyway, there is still not the right code to understand and reproduce the issue. This is still not a [mcve].

Comment: @DidierL: Notice the line - future = future.thenRunAsync(). So waitForWriteComplete() is working as expected (verified by actual execution on production data). And, there is no more code to this than what I have here, literally :) If you can't understand the issue, then you can't. :)

Comment: @Bonton255 sorry, missed that… I guess this explains the cause of your issue then, so I posted the comment I was about to write as an answer :-) I just had to make some assumptions on how `DataItemCache` is declared and accessed in production as there are no annotations or sample code here – just a unit test which, as I understand, does not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the `future` that you store in `DataItemCache`, this service is stateful.

Assuming it is a singleton, the chain of `CompletableFuture`s that you build is shared across all callers. This means that if you call `saveItemAsync()` in parallel, you will build a huge chain of `CompletableFuture`. It is likely to be the cause of your OOME.

Moreover, the `waitForWriteComplete()` will also wait for other callers' futures to complete, while possibly missing its own results – as there is no synchronization when accessing `future`.

Finally, since all calls are chained, the side effect is that only one is processed at a time (except due to memory synchronization issues when accessing `future`). There is thus not much point of using `CompletableFuture` here, it would be much simpler to have a `synchronized` synchronous method. This would also consume less memory, and probably improve the performance by avoiding all the overhead of `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But I already know what you have mentioned here. The question was why are the CompletableFutures that have finished executing, not freeing up the memory. And how I can make them free up the memory after they have finished executing? As a side note, the use of CompletableFuture here (instead of a synchronous method), is obviously to not have the consumer wait for the save calls to finish while the consumer can go back and do more work.

Comment: I think `CompletableFuture` is quite well optimized with regards to memory management, but the GC might have a hard time to discard them due to the long chains that you build. You might want to check the "shortest paths to GC roots" in Eclipse Memory Analyzer to have a better understanding. Are you sure they all have finished executing when you get the OOME? Additionally, you could considerably reduce the number of `CompletableFuture`s by processing full batches of `DataItem`s inside `thenRunAsync()`, without performance impact since there is already no parallelism there.